How can I merge two dictionaries in Python without losing any data?
I'm trying to merge two dictionaries in Python, but I'm having trouble ensuring that data from both dictionaries is preserved. If a key exists in both dictionaries, I want to combine their values into a list.
dict1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
dict2 = {'b': 3, 'c': 4, 'd': 5}

merged_dict = dict1.copy()
for key, value in dict2.items():
    if key in merged_dict:
        merged_dict[key] = [merged_dict[key], value]
    else:
        merged_dict[key] = value

print(merged_dict)

The output I'm getting is:
{'a': 1, 'b': [2, 3], 'c': [3, 4], 'd': 5}

This works, but if there are already lists as values, this approach doesn't handle it well. For example, mergin
dict1 = {'a': [1], 'b': 2}
dict2 = {'a': 3, 'b': [4], 'c': 5}

Desired output:
{'a': [1, 3], 'b': [2, 4], 'c': 5}

How can I improve my function to handle this situation more generally? Is there a more Pythonic way to merge dictionaries while ensuring all values are combined into lists if keys overlap?

What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?  When you debug your code, which operation is producing an unexpected result?

I would strongly suggest to review the source of your dicts, and make sure that values are always lists, and the desired output is a dict whose values are also always lists. Type consistency is something to cherish.

You will also have problems with shallow copying a dictionary containing lists. The problem is presented is under-specified.

you should almost certainly fix whatever is causing the keys to have different types in the first place. that will make your merging code much cleaner than if you have to handle different types. you continuing the problem in your own merging by doing this: merged_dict[key] = value instead of merged_dict[key] = [value]

@KellyBundy I don't understand what you are saying. Do you mean to say I should have written "that the values corresponding to the same keys should be of the same type?"

@KellyBundy yes, I was using "key has type X" to mean "key has a value of type X", I agree that was imprecise and misleading

You should want the result of {'a': [1, 3], 'b': [2, 4], 'c': [5]} since you would have uniform handling of the result...

you need to check if type of key is list or a number and based on that merge or append the values
here is the code
dict1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
dict2 = {'b': 3, 'c': 4, 'd': 5}
 
from collections import defaultdict

def merge_dicts(dict1, dict2):

    merged_dict = defaultdict(list)

    for d in (dict1, dict2):
        for key, value in d.items():
            if isinstance(value, list):
                merged_dict[key].extend(value)
            else:
                merged_dict[key].append(value)
    return dict(merged_dict)
 
result = merge_dicts(dict1, dict2)
print(result) # {'a': [1], 'c': [3, 4], 'b': [2, 3], 'd': [5]}



I think that answer would be to create the key, value pair and add it to a new dictionary, this allows to transform the value of the corresponding keys in a list and then just append each element to an empty dictionary, let me know if this answers your question.
Here is an example:
def merge_dictionaries(dict1, dict2):
    merged_dict = {}

# Add all keys from the first dictionary
    for key, value in dict1.items():
        if key in dict2:
# Combine values into a list
            merged_dict[key] = [value] if not isinstance(value, list) else value
            merged_dict[key].append(dict2[key])
        else:
        # Add value as-is
            merged_dict[key] = value

# Add remaining keys from the second dictionary
    for key, value in dict2.items():
        if key not in dict1:
            merged_dict[key] = value

# Flatten lists if necessary
    for key, value in merged_dict.items():
        if isinstance(value, list):
            merged_dict[key] = [v for sublist in value for v in (sublist if isinstance(sublist, list) else [sublist])]

    return merged_dict


You might use set arithmetic for detecting which keys are in both dicts and which keys are exactly in one following way and then process each accordingly
import collections
dict1 = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
dict2 = {'b': 3, 'c': 4, 'd': 5}
double = set(dict1).intersection(dict2)
single = set(dict1).symmetric_difference(dict2)
merged = {k: collections.ChainMap(dict1, dict2)[k] for k in single} | {k:[dict1[k],dict2[k]] for k in double}
print(merged)  # {'d': 5, 'a': 1, 'c': [3, 4], 'b': [2, 3]}

Note that | here is one as described PEP 584 and as such requires python3.9 or newer to work. See linked material if you need to port it to older versions.
